# how can i bind image to lazy list getting from xml parametes

Tags: android

i am getting the text message and image from the .net web server by sending the xml parameters.

i need to display these messages and images using [lazy list Concept](http://open-pim.com/tmp/LazyList.zip).

I am getting messages by sending the xml parameters and display them in lazy list.

but in the above sample they using url to get the images but i am getting images from xml parameters.

i am getting confusion.can any one please help me how can i display images getting from xml parameters.

thanks in advance.

(let me add comment if any one doe's n't understand my question)

Answer (score 2):

The SAX XML parser is available on Android and can read from any class that implements InputStream. Since URLConnection provides a way to return its underlying InputStream, it seems to me you could do something like the following...

```
URL xmlSource = new URL("some http path");
UrlConnection xmlConnection = xmlSource.openConnection();
org.xml.sax.InputSource xmlStream = new InputSource(xmlConnection.getInputStream());
```

I haven't tested this myself and Google is careful to warn that the included Sax implementation comes as-is, but it seems to me a good place to start. There are plenty of resources available online on using InputSource and implementing Sax callbacks.